# An error has occurred - please try your action again

Tags: bug, status-norepro, documentation, review-queues, error-message

While trying to approve [this document review](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/125236), I always receive the following error:

> An error has occurred - please try your action again.

When I skip this review I'm still able to re-evaluate it when accessing it from the history (and this will reproduce the issue). I can approve/reject any other review, so it is specific to this review. The same issue has already been noticed by someone else.

Any clues on what would trigger this?

[image: Error print-screen]

Comment: Did you try again, did it work the second time? It normally means there was a network error (which could have been from the proxy provider Stack Overflow uses, it sometimes produces a 500 error too).

Comment: The error is otherwise pretty generic and can pop up anywhere an asynchronous action is taken (like reviewing, commenting, flagging, closing, etc.).

Comment: I tried again, even reloaded browser and it didn't help. (I won't be able to try any upcoming solutions as I just got a 2 day ban by failing a single audit...)

Comment: Hrm, it *could* be related to your ban then. Can you add that to your question, or are you sure you didn't have that ban yet when you created the screenshot?

Comment: I'm sure. When the issue occurred, I tried 40 minutes later with the same result and got banned 15 minutes after that retry. Could it be that I was in a sort of "pre-ban" status? The weird part is that I could skip that review and successfully approve the next one.

Comment: There is no 'pre-ban status'. So the error occurs for a *specific, single documenation review*? Consistently?

Comment: Yes, see the first link in my post above.

Comment: Excellent; that means we'll have to wait for a Stack Overflow dev to look into this; the community can't really help here. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Thank you! Even if this isn't really a top priority issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report!

Unfortunately, the best answer I can give here is "no idea what happened". Other users were able to vote to approve or reject that proposed change, so this has to be something specific both to you and to that change. We haven't had similar reports that I'm aware of, so I'm inclined to call this one a weird one-off.

Please do let us know if you see something similar happen again, though.